# VBA SQL Aggregate memo field

Tags: sql, excel, vba, aggregation, adodb

I have query from Excel file that retrieves key and description (memo field).

Source:

```
key  | description
k1     long variable text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
k2     long variable text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
k3     long variable text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
k1     shorter than k1 text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
k2             
k1     could be also empty
```

Result:

```
KEY    DESCRIPTION
k1     long variable text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
k2     long variable text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
k3     long variable text (memo) maybe up to 1000 char
```

My code is

```
SELECT 
    key as KEY, 
    IIF(Count(description) = 1, MAX(description), COUNT(description)) AS DESCRIPTION 
FROM Source 
GROUP BY key
```

But Excel returns an error that it cannot aggregate a memo field.

Is there some elegant solution?

I use ADOdb with Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

```
Sub getRs(strSQL As String)
Dim strConn As String
Dim i As Integer

strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

End Sub
```

Connecting to other workbook looks like  (I do not think it is issue)

```
    "SELECT --Look above-- FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src2.xlsb' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;']"
```

Now I try to "cut" description by LEN and IIF function:

```
  SELECT 
    [key] as [KEY], 
    IIF(Count([description]) = 1, 
         IIF(LEN([description])>255, 
            '[CUT]' & MAX(LEFT([description],240)), 
            COUNT([description])), 
         IIF(LEN([description])>255, 
            '[[CUT]' & MAX(LEFT([description],240)) & ']', 
            '[' & COUNT([description]) & ']' )) AS [DESCRIPTION]
   FROM Source 
   GROUP BY [key]
```

[but now I have this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp458.png)

Comment: Please give some more information. In which way you execute your query?

Comment: I extended my question. I use recordset open and copyfromrecordset to destination.